# How to Inject dependencies when using MethodDecorator.Fody

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, custom-attributes, fody

I am trying to use MethodDevorator.Fody to enable Attribute based method interception.

https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator/blob/master/readme.md#your-code

I wanted to create a reusable component (nuget package), expecting consumers to give configuration information injected to service collection.
But I dont find any standard way to inject dependencies to attribute
Please provide any workarounds to achieve this